# Web AppBuilder Query results hyperlink

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

In the query widget in the Web AppBuilder, I am trying to get one of the result fields to display as a hyperlink, but I am having trouble.

In the “Results Setting” tab in the query widget, I’ve set the URL field’s Special Type as “Link”. I click OK and save the Web App.

[image]

When the query is run, the results display the field, but the hyperlink in the results window is not active. Nor is the hyperlink active in the pop up when one of these results is clicked on the map.

[image]
[image]

However, the link is active if the result layer’s attribute table is open.

[image]

If I go back to edit mode in the query widget, the Special Type for the field is back to “None”. The “Link” type does not hold.

[image]

Is there a way to get the Special Type to remain “Link”? I don’t believe it is a problem with the URL itself, as the hyperlink is activated and working in the attribute table.

The app is using a Map Service that was uploaded onto AGOL from a local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some digging online led me to an ESRI Geonet forum discussing this exact problem and a solution:

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/132837

This issue is a bug and you can update the config_Query.json file to change the type to "link". Check out the link for more details.